# State doesn't update

Tags: android, state, android-jetpack-compose

My state doesn't update if I call the function: flipButtonClicked()
Does someone know why?

```
class FlipCardViewModel(cardState: CardState): ViewModel() {
private var _state by mutableStateOf(
    cardState
)

val state: CardState
    get() = _state

fun flipButtonClicked(){
    _state.isFlipped = !_state.isFlipped
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign new instance to `_state`, changing property of an Object doesn't trigger recomposition by default.

If your `CardState` is a data class you can do it as

```
fun flipButtonClicked(){
    _state = _state.copy(!_state.isFlipped)
}}
```

Comment: That don't work.

Comment: Ma' solution work!! It work like an buffalo in a field!!

Comment: Dr. Thacian, you approved an edit on the post. Please reconsider it, since in some native languages, the formation of the question is considered standard. It might be inappropriate if you try to edit/specify it.

Answer (score -1):

Ma' man your state don't update cuz' you didn't do no reading of the docs.

Just initialise the state variable like

`var state by mutableStateOf(cardState)`

and update it like

`state = state.copy(!state.isFlipped)`

Why add unnecessary complicated third party calls?

EDIT: Localised accent is devoted to the "Original" Post by the author, before someone decided to edit it out to localise it for "themselves".